# How to make a requirejs module with multiple files

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I was wondering how to make a requirejs module with multiple files.
e.x. I require one file which then somehow gets multiple files.
I know I could do this:

```
define([all the other files], function () {
  var mod = {},
      files = [all the other files];   
  arguments.forEach(function (i) {
    mod.[files[i]] = i;
  });
  return mod;

});
```

but I was wondering whether there was a better method?

Comment: Have a look at this - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename

Comment: That's not what I'm asking for, It's the complete opposite, I want one module, multiple files, module name is for one file, multiple modules.

Comment: AFAIK, `arguments` does not have a `forEach` method, but I understand the pseudo-code. What you suggest seems the simplest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a dynamic list of files(.txt,.tpl,.htm,.json), to avoid a change in JS source code to add more files.

I don't know if is there a way to do that, but you must take care about the time that will take to download all this files. I suggest you to create a json file with all files that you want to download, and iterate through this array of files using ajax to get them.

If you are try to get all module inside a directory, you need to create a js file: `<package-all>.js` that encapsulate an `require([all files],function());` for example.

I believe that this is the only way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

first, write the modules like this,

```
define(function(){
    return {
        'mod-a' : require('modules/mod-a'),
        'mod-b' : require('modules/mod-b'),
        'mod-c' : require('modules/mod-c')

    }
})
```

then use r.js to optimize the above js to blow one (r.js will combine all module file to one), or, you can write like this directly :

```
define('modules/mod-a', [], function(){});
define('modules/mod-b', [], function(){});
define('modules/mod-c', [], function(){});

define('mod-all', ['modules/mod-a','modules/mod-b','modules/mod-c'], function(){

    return {
        'mod-a' : require('modules/mod-a'),
        'mod-b' : require('modules/mod-b'),
        'mod-c' : require('modules/mod-c')
    }
})
```

now, the modules 'mod-all' is the thing you wanted.